# I need some thoughts about the design of my database, related to storing coordinates

Tags: mysql, database, coordinates

I want to design a database for storing the location (latitude and longitude) of several buses (it would be a tracking app). So, I will have one device in each bus, sending this location every 10 seconds to the server, storing it in the database. And I will also have clients that will look up for the location of a given bus.

I have thought about 2 possible solutions, one would be creating 2 tables, one to store the complete report with next columns: bus number, timedate, latitude and longitude. And the second table the same, but just to store the last location, so the entries of this table for the buses would be updating all the time. In the first one I would have a lot of rows, growing too fast, thats why I thought about creating a second table to just store the last location and improve the performance of the client querys.

And the reason why I don't keep just this second table (that would be enough for the clients functionality), is because I want a complete report to be able to have statistics.

The second solution would be just creating one table with all the reports, and when a client wants to know the location, I would look for the last one ordering by the timedate of that specific bus. But as I said before, if the table is growing too much, this will take maybe too many time in the future. Other possibility is to clean the database entries every week for example, take statistics, store them in one table and clean the main one.

So, in addition, I also would like to know what should be the primary key in that table. I have read that using timedate as primary key is not adviced, because sometimes if the difference in time is too small, it will take it as the same timedate and wont store the entry. But as I will be reporting every 10 seconds, maybe it shouldn't be a problem. Other option is to add an ID for every report, but I think it would be just a waste of space. Or maybe I could have it without primary key (something that I think is not adviced too...).

For the second table, I would use the line number of the bus as primary key, because I would have just one entry (the last one) for every bus, so there wouldn't be repetitions.

Any help about all of this? I'm quite newb as you can see in this area and I would appreciate it very much.

So to sum up, my questions are:

- It would improve the performance having 2 tables or just 1 is enough?
- What would be the primary key in the table with all the reports?

Thank you for reading and for helping :D

Answer (score 1):

Just go with the two tables approach. Simple and clean.

IMHO stick with a simple auto-increment integer key on the big table. Many engines will create one for you anyway if you dont (so its not saving anything by not creating it)

As a simple number its also great for ordering results by date (technically the order they received, but should be generally be the same). Will perform better than date-ordering, and doesnt require another index creating.

(timestamp not good. because while it should generally be unique for one bus, what if all busses happen to send their update at the same second()

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I think I will use then the auto-increment integer.

The only thing is that I must keep the datetime column, because I must check if its recent to see if I show the result or not. For example if a bus gps stops working, I would be showing always the same position, I think I should compare it with the current date and time, and see if the difference is small enough (for example 60 seconds).

So I will add an integer as primary key, and I will keep all the others columns. Thank you again :D

Comment: YEs, absolutely store the timestamp. In both tables.